# Display Multiple Card Themes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

If I need 4 different style cards with different elevation, color etc across application. How to implement in theme manager in Flutter? Example something like below.

Here is an example:

```
ThemeData getApplicationTheme() {
  return ThemeData(
      cardTheme1: CardTheme(color:ColorManager.white,shadowColor: ColorManager.grey,
          elevation: AppSize.s4),
      cardTheme2: CardTheme(color:ColorManager.white,shadowColor: ColorManager.grey,
          elevation: AppSize.s10),
      cardTheme3: CardTheme(color:ColorManager.white,shadowColor: ColorManager.grey,
          elevation: AppSize.s15),}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `CardTheme` per `ThemeData`. But you can use the `Theme` widget to change theme in part of the widget tree. So you can put a `Card` widgets as child to a `Theme` widgets. Or multiple `Cards` in a `Row` or `Column` with the same `Theme`.